# Moved Application to New Computer Won't Run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an application that I recently moved to another computer, where it won't run. Previously the application had a different name and a different target. I updated the new information and it runs fine on the original computer, but I can't get it to run on the iOS Simulator on the new computer. The play button is completely greyed out. Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: 8/8/2011 13:44

I'm not sure if this helps, but when I go to the Product menu and select "Edit Schemes" it is listing the old application target (which it says is missing). However, I can't find a way to change that in that menu.

FOUND SOLUTION:

I found that by going into the Product menu and selecting "Manage Schemes" that a new window came up. In this window I clicked a button that says, "Autocreate schemes now" and a new scheme with the new app name appeared. Then I went into the Product menu and clicked "Edit Scheme" and another window came up. In this menu, the new scheme was available from the "Scheme" drop down. I selected it, and now all is well.

Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Comment: Have you set up your developer certificate?

Comment: The developer certificate was set up for the original application, but worked fine with the name change on the original computer. It worked on the new computer under the old name as well.

Comment: So the problem isn't the new computer but the new name?

Comment: It seems to be the new computer. When I changed the name using the original computer, it still ran on the original computer. However, when I moved the code for the application with the name changed to the new computer it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 0):

In most all cases, this is caused by the configured SDK version of the application not being present on the newer computer.  To adjust this, go to the project settings and adjust the Base SDK to a version that is present on the new computer.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the solution. The SDK was already set a version that is present on the new computer. Both computers are running 4.3.